# getting error that Error:SQL problems: Inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I wrote a query. The problem is if i remove the case statement then error disappear but if i use the case statement then error comes and case statement is necessary. Here is the query

```
Select
b.branch_name AS "BRANCHES",                         --varchar2(100 byte)
(
    Select count(temp.loan_acct_no)                  --varchar2(30 byte)
    From
        (
            Select *
            From
                Losa_app app
            inner join
                losa_cust lc
            on
                (lc.app_ref_no = app.app_ref_no )   --varchar2(20 byte)
            and
                lc.app_joint_T= 'P'                 --varchar2(10 byte)
            inner join
                losa_facilities lf
            on
                (lf.app_ref_no = app.app_ref_no)    --varchar2(20 byte)
        )
        temp
    where
        temp.attend_branch = b.branch_id            --NUMBER(10, 0)
) AS "No.of Account"
From
    code_branch b
where
    b.branch_code1                                  --varchar2(16 byte)
like
    case :inputChannel
        when 'AIBB' Then '0347%'                    --AIBB or ABB (varchar2(10 byte))
        When 'ABB'  Then '0232%' 
    end
```

In this case error comes but if i remove the lines

```
where
    b.branch_code1
like
    case :inputChannel
        when 'AIBB' Then '0347%'    
        When 'ABB'  Then '0232%' 
    end
```

Then error gone. I think error is coming because my case statement is returning char data. How can i convert my case statement to return number instead of char ?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you could specify the data types of all involved columns. Furthermore, you should give more information about the `:inputChannel` parameter. From what environment are you running this SQL? (It's relevant due to the use of parameters.)

Comment: I am running it in oracle. Actually when i run query on sqlDeveloper then it runs fine. But when i put this query in iReport then the error comes. And after removing the where clause as i mentioned above, the data type it shows of `No of Account` is `java.math.Bigdecimal`. I have added the data types, you can check now...

Answer (score 0):

done. I request to administrator that move this question to iReport section. Because the query is right but i did something wrong while put this query in the iReport. Actually in oracle when we want input then we write like `:inputChannel`. For same thing in iReport we define parameters like `$P{inputChannel}`. So what i did wrong is that when i defined the parameter `$P{inputChannel}`, then i didn't set its `Default value expression` which should be `""`. AFter doing this error gone in iReport.

I don't know how to move it to iReport section otherwise i do it by myself. Sorry but i thought may be i am doing something wrong with the query, sorry :(